# PostgreSQL: set default privileges on schemas themselves?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

According to the PostgreSQL documentation on `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`, default privileges can be set on tables, sequences, functions, types.

Is there any way to set default privileges on schemas themselves, so that the privileges specified in the `GRANT` clause are by default applied to any new schema in the database upon its creation?

Comment: I think your best option is an event trigger on `CREATE SCHEMA`.

Comment: Postgres 10 will allow this

Comment: @dezso:  Is it really possible to create such a trigger?

Comment: @user1071847 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/event-triggers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name, this is now implemented in [PostgreSQL v10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES allows you to set the privileges that will be applied to objects created in the future. (It does not affect privileges assigned to already-existing objects.) Currently, only the privileges for **schemas**, tables (including views and foreign tables), sequences, functions, and types (including domains) can be altered.

Example,

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
  GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMAS
  TO role;
```